# AJAX - ASP.NET - Timer delay problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, timer

I'm trying to make an webapplication where you see an Ajax countdown timer. Whenever I push a button the countdown should go back to 30 and keep counting down.

Now the problem is whenever I push the button the timer keeps counting down for a second or 2 and most of the time after that the timer keeps standing on 30 for to long.

WebForm code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="geen verbinding"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
        <br />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
</asp:Timer>

</form>
```

Code Behind:

```
static int timer = 30;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = timer.ToString();
}
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer--;

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer = 30;         
}
```

Hope somebody knows what the problem is and if there is anyway to fix this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you start your timer??

Comment: If not defined it auto starts at site load.

Comment: When would you like it to start? Just on the button click?

Comment: The starting is ok, thats not the problem. The problem is that the timer doesn't react correctly on the button click. I need those to be perfectly the same (the client timer and server timer), and when the button is clicked the server timer should move back to 30, so that would be the same for the client timer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you implement the Timer entirely on the ClientSide? Can you explain why it has to be a callback? What does it need to do on the Server?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var timer = 0;
function resetTimer() {
    timer = 0;
    timerTick();
}
function timerTick() {
    var target = document.getElementById("timerResult");

    target.innerHTML = timer++;
    window.setTimeout("timerTick()", 1000);
}
</script>
```

And in the body tag...

```
<body onload="timerTick();">
```

And somewhere to display

```
<div id="timerResult" >timerResult</div>
```

You justy have to add a button chich calls resetTimer(). I'll leave that  to you

Comment: I've a timer on server side and the client timer needs to be corrected every second by the server timer.